# jrecorder not working on cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 domains let D1 and D2
I am using jrecorder plugin on D1, here I give path of host to other domain D2, path to my D2 server is in $.cookie("obj12"),everything is working fine until i go on cross domain for D2 server. If I give server name of same domain that is D1 to D1, it works fine.
How to make it work on cross domain, I have acceptfile.php on domain D2 and here i want to save the file

```
var obj12 =new String($.cookie("obj12"));
                            alert(obj12);
                            $.jRecorder
                            (

                                {

                                    host : obj12 ,  please
                                    callback_started_recording:     function(){callback_started();},
                                    callback_stopped_recording:     function(){callback_stopped();},
                                    callback_activityLevel:          function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
                                    callback_activityTime:     function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },
                                    callback_finished_sending:     function(time){ callback_finished_sending();},
                                    swf_path : 'jRecorder.swf'

                                }
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of security issus.
you can not do crossdomain commands with js and from browsers, if there is a real need in jobs like that you can use web services which should be explicitly be written for you.
i my self have no experience with webservices but know thats the way because you have to set the servers talk together not a page from ine server to other server

Comment: ok,but on https://github.com/sythoos/jRecorder/blob/master/html/example1.html, line number 52, its given to give server path. @Homam

Comment: thats right, but is it another server, else you said its working well on the same domain and the problem is **crossdomain**

Comment: ok, is there any way that I save the file on client side and then import to server on other domain? @Homam

Comment: **honestly I DO NOT KNOW** :D